# Transimpedance amplifier maximum current resolution

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, current-measurement, precision

Maybe this question is a bit too general but I don't seem to find any solution.

I want to build a current sensor for a current that ranges from 1uA to 1mA and needs resolutions of nearly 1pA.

I know about the TIA topology and that you can measure currents of 1pA and below with proper component selection and PCB layout but I think they have very limited range, like 1pA to 10pA. I want resolution, hence, **the question is what resolutions can you expect from TIAs for input currents of around 1uA to 1mA? And what other current sensing topologies are there?**

Below is the schematic of the TIA I currently have and the layout of the PCB:

[image: TIA schematic]
[image: Layout]

Comment: What's your bw?

Comment: The terminology is a bit off. The term resolution of a measurement is related to an ADC and has nothing to do with an analog measurement. To have a resolution of 1 pA at 1 mA range you need an ADC with at least 30 bits. But that is probably not what you are really asking.

Comment: Do you expect to get 1 pA resolution at 1 mA range, or at 1 µA range? The first is in my opinion impossible in practice, the latter may be reached in the best case - but is hard too. If you have a fixed gain, first decide what the measurement range should be. @LarsHankeln correct statement too.

Comment: Since the OP is not asking about ADCs, I suppose they are interested in analog SNR and not digitized "resolution". At least that is what I assumed when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A TIA is a good appraoch for this. It is not impossible for the TIA circuit to have the necessary SNR of 1e9 (equivalent to 1 ppb  precision), BUT:

- linearity, gain drift and offset drift (thus accuracy) will be much worse than 1 ppb
- the closer you get to DC, the more the 1/f noise of the op-amp and gain resistor will crash your party.

Comment: `the closer you get to DC, the more the 1/f noise of the op-amp and gain resistor will crash your party.` what about using an integrating TIA *(i.e. having a cap instead of a resistor on the FB path)* then?

Comment: @RohatKılıç That'd be a charge amplifier. It can't be used for (large) DC currents obviously, so there is no benefit for low frequencies. It also doesn't get rid of the 1/f noise of the opamp because after the differentiation of the output signal, any 1/f input current will be still there. However, that approach does actually eliminate some accuracy concerns (first bullet), but needs chopping for low frequency signals (think dual slope or delta-sigma ADCs).

Comment: @tobalt Thank you for your reply, do have any reference designs for very high precision TIA?

Comment: @WeijieChen no. Well it is really just 3 components. If you have to work at DC, choose zero-drift opamp and resistor with very low material noise index

Comment: In view of the expected resolution, i suggest a guard line around your op amp, on the PCB, to minimize leakage currents.